# What is morph target animation?

Tags: animation, terminology

I've been using Adobe Flash and its keyframe-based animation for some years.
I recently about heard morph-targets animation from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morph_target_animation).

It seems that the morph target animation is also keyframe-based.
What are the differences between Flash's animation and morph target animation?

Answer (score 1):

In short, they are actually very similar and just differ by 2D vs. 3D.

Flash's animation uses keyframes, and blends control points between those keyframes.

Morph target animation also uses keyframes, and blends the vertices between those frames.

The primary difference is the data involved. Flash is working with 2D vector graphics, so there are points, edges, line sizes, colors, etc. Whereas in the case of morph targets, it's just the position of the vertices.